# fancybox-overlay display two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I need help. I tried more or less within a fancybox displaying a photo and next to the picture show with facebook comments social plugin.

within the fancybox options Javascript, I have a

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
 padding: 0,
    modal: true,
        helpers: {
        thumbs : {
                    width  : 50,
                    height : 50
                },
        buttons: {},

        },

    afterShow: function(){
        var descripcion = "<div class='texto1'><p>TEXTO1</p></div>"
        var comentarios = "<div class='texto2'><p>TEXTO2</p></div>;"
        $('#fancybox-overlay').append(comentarios);
        $('#fancybox-overlay').append(descripcion);

    },
    nextEffect: 'fade',
    prevEffect: 'fade'
});
```

the problem is it wont let me show the overlay the two things at once, only one or the other ... : S have any solution so you can show both? thank you in advance

Comment: you have a syntax error when defining the vars `descripcion` and `comentarios` ... each should be closed with semicolon `;` ... the first one is missing and the second is inside the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I clearly understand what you are expecting it to do :

```
afterShow: function(){
    var descripcion = '<div class="texto1"><p>TEXTO1</p></div>';
    var comentarios = '<div class="texto2"><p>TEXTO2</p></div>';
    $('#fancybox-overlay').append(descripcion, comentarios);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I hope to show me two tasks at once, but I do not know why only the last to run out.

I've tried your solution and I do not work, only shows a variable of two

Comment: How about `$('#fancybox-overlay').append(descripcion + comentarios);`

Comment: whit $('#fancybox-overlay').append(descripcion + comentarios); does not work . it displayed only the last variable

Comment: neither does work with :

var a ="<div class='texto1'>Hola</div><br><div class='texto2'>Adios</div>";
$('#fancybox-overlay').html(a);

Comment: The last thing I can think of is to use dollar sign. `.append($(descripcion), $(comentarios))`

Comment: Just for the record (for future visitors) `$('#fancybox-overlay')` is not a valid selector in fancybox v2.x ... it should be `$('.fancybox-overlay')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for the syntax mistakes ... then you can create a wrapper to insert your new text inside fancybox, let's say

```
<div class='wrapText'></div>
```

... with some style to position it correctly

```
.wrapText {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1100;
    color : #fff;
}
```

... then prepend it to fancybox content using the `beforeShow` callback

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeShow: function () {
      var descripcion = "<div class='texto1'><p>TEXTO1</p></div>";
      var comentarios = "<div class='texto2'><p>TEXTO2</p></div>";
      $("<div class='wrapText'>" +descripcion+comentarios+ "</div>")
        .prependTo( this.inner );
    }
});
```

[SEE it working](http://jsfiddle.net/65B98/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I have copied your example in my code to test it in my project, but the text is not displayed: S, however in your demo yes. On the other hand wanted to specify that my intention is to insert each text into two differents css style

Comment: Thank you very much, in fact the problem was in the CSS, excuse my slip, I did not know that getting a valid response I should click on the stick,sorry. I'm new to the forum. My sincere thanks for your help, and sorry for my English